# ASP.NET VB - How to access data from dynamically created TextBox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dynamic

Firstly, I'm a beginner programmer in ASP.NET(VB). As stated in the title how do i access the value of a dynamically created texbox

For example : On Aspx Page

```
<asp:Table id= "Table1" runat="server">
</asp:Table>
```

On Aspx.Vb page on Page_Load, I have

```
dim i as integer = 0

While i < 3
  Dim tempCell as New TableCell
  Dim tempCell2 as New TableCell
  Dim temprow as New TableRow 

  tempCell.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<asp:TextBox id = 'aa" & i & "' runat="server">this is value for ab " & i & "</asp:TextBox>"))
  tempCell2.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<asp:TextBox id = 'ab" & i & "' runat="server">this is value for ab " & i & "</asp:TextBox>"))

  temprow.Cells.Add(tempCell) 
  temprow.Cells.Add(tempCell2)

  Table1.Rows.Add(temprow)

  i = i + 1
End While
```

So, this is roughly what I wanted to do.

The code works, except that, How do i get the data on button click? 
I've done some google search but couldn't get to an anwser.
I've tried the page.FindControl("ab" & i), but i still can't get the value.

Where did I do wrong with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use directcast to access your cells. Here's an example code I wrote to access a dynamically generated textbox.

```
Dim txt = New TextBox()
txt.Name = "name1"
txt.Size = New Size(200, 70)
txt.Location = New Point(40, 40)
txt.Text = "I am a new textbox"
Me.Controls.Add(txt)
DirectCast(Me.Controls("name1"), TextBox).Text = "Some stuff here" 'The magic happens here
```

Comment: Thanks alot for this.